# Equivalent of "info locals" to dump local variable in hex

Tags: gdb

Do we have an equivalent of  "info locals" to dump local variable in hex?

```
(gdb) info locals
sa = 33554433
dp = 16
pr = 6
da = 67108865
sp = 16
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [set output-radix 16](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Numbers.html). Example:

```
Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:3
3         int a = 12, b = 42;
(gdb) n      
4         return a + b;
(gdb) info locals
a = 12
b = 42

(gdb) set output-radix 16
Output radix now set to decimal 16, hex 10, octal 20.

(gdb) info locals
a = 0xc
b = 0x2a
```